# How to point subdomain to a nameserver?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I've got an old crusty WHM/cPanel server which I'm trying to get rid of. I've got a new setup on shared hosting which is much cheaper in the long run.

The problem is that there are a bunch of websites on the server whose domains I don't have access to. They're currently pointing to name servers of my domain (`ns.mydomain.com`), but the new provider has their own name servers (`ns.provider.com`) which I have to use instead.

My initial idea was to set up a CNAME to point my name server to my provider's: `ns.mydomain.com CNAME ns.provider.com`, but I read [in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/324181/can-i-use-a-cname-to-point-to-a-3rd-parties-ns-servers) that this would be a bad idea. The accepted answer suggests using an A record instead, and I want to make sure how this would work.

Assuming `ns.provider.com` has an IP address of `123.123.123.123`, is it just a matter of doing `ns.mydomain.com A 123.123.123.123`? Is there any way the provider could block those requests as the name server domain technically doesn't belong to them?

Comment: The provider's name servers usually have to be configured to be a name server for your domain for this to work.

Comment: Perhaps crucial to you understanding of the issue and why you've even asked this question: *Domains don't point to nameservers. Nameservers point to domains.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need the following setup?

```
hosteddomain.com
NS record: ns.mydomain.com

mydomain.com
NS record: ns.mydomain.com
A record: ns.mydomain.com > 123.123.123.123
```

where 123.123.123.123 is the IP of the new providers name server.

As long as the provider has the DNS records for those domains then it should work fine.

I don't see that they would block the requests for hosteddomain.com as long as the domain/dns is hosted using their services.