# Cname record to dns server

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, cname-record, dns-hosting

I have a nameserver of my hoster called **ns1.hoster.com**. I would like users of my  (hosted) application to use my branded nameserver called **ns1.mybrand.com**.

**ns1.mybrand.com points to ns1.hoster.com (Cname)**

But this doesn't work. If I try to setup a domain at my registrar (point nameserver to ns1.mybrand.com), I get the following error:

> The hosts [ns1.mybrand.com,ns2.mybrand.com] are not registered name
>   servers.

It works when I try **ns1.hoster.com** directly.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: ns to cname.. bad idea ... http://serverfault.com/questions/222641/in-dns-can-an-in-ns-point-to-a-cname

Comment: So I should setup my own DNS server? But what kind of record does ns1.mybrand.com needs to be to point it to my own dns server setup? Mybrand.com uses the dns server of the registrar.

Comment: You are going to need to run your own DNS servers if this is something you require.  I don't understand how you think you registrar would even support having your customers point at their name servers.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you want to achieve by having your users use *ns1.mybrand.com* instead of *ns1.hoster.com*?

Answer (score 3):

You should think of this differently,

nsx.mybrand.com is a different zone (and file) to nsx.hoster.com, so as just create normal A records in your mybrand.com zone file and use the same IPs as the nsx.mybrand.com name servers.

This will do what you want, I've being doing it for many years.

Example. registered name server ns1.hoster.com and ns2.hoster.com

in the forward zone file for mybrand.com, add:

NS1 IN A 1.2.3.4 (ip address of ns1.hoster.com)

NS2 IN A 1.2.3.5 (ip address of ns2.hoster.com)

You can then use NS1.mybrand.com NS2.mybrand.com as if they where registered name servers nsx.hoster.com. All of the of queries go to the real name servers so everything works as expected.

hope this makes sense.

Comment: I've tried to do this, But it doesn't work. But this is the solution I was thinking of. My registrar doesn't allow nsx.mybrand.com (A records that points to nsx.myhoster.com) as nameserver. I get the error nsx.mybrand.com is not a registered nameserver. If I point directly to nsx.myhoster.com it works. But then I don't use my brandname....