# pointing different records to a CNAME record

Tags: mx-record, cname-record, ptr-record, ns-record

I am trying to figure out the following and want to know "why" this is or is not possible.

1. May an MX record “point to” a CNAME record?
2. May a CNAME record “point to” a CNAME record?
3. May an A record “point to” a CNAME record?
4. May a PTR record “point to” a CNAME record?
5. May an NS record “point to” a CNAME record?

Are there official rules for pointing records to CNAME records?

Comment: Have you read the RFC yet?

Comment: Typing 'CNAME' into google and looking at the first few links should answer *all* of your questions.

Comment: `following and want to know "why" this is or is not possible.` - because that is the way they wrote the specification.

Answer (score 2):

Short answers:

1. No
2. Yes
3. No
4. No
5. No

Long answers: (edit in progress)

1. No as per the standard. Ths was clarified in RFC-2181 sectin 10.3.
2. Standard says that it is possible, but not a good practice and should be avoided whenever possible. There's a risk of creating loops, slowing down name resolution and failure by broken resolver libraries.
3. I may not understand the question properly - the data of an A record is an IPv4 address - i don't see how it could point to a cname.
4. This is not legal, as clarified in RFC-2181 section 10.2
5. This has been properly answered in [In DNS can an IN NS point to a CNAME?](https://serverfault.com/questions/222641/in-dns-can-an-in-ns-point-to-a-cname)

Comment: "This is not legal, as clarified in RFC-2181 section 10.2": statement is incorrect. The [RFC in question](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2181#section-10.2) does not forbid that, but... ahem, rather clumsily argues, with an excess of _conditional_ tenses, that it _should_ be avoided. Someone _should_ rewrite that section one of these days  ;-)  @Pietertje is quite correct about this.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if i'm wrong but i think this is your answer.

> May an MX record “point to” a CNAME record?

No it is stated in the RFC that an MX, record should not point to a CNAME record.

> May a CNAME record “point to” a CNAME record?

Yes, it is allowed. But it is not considered good practise, this could cause a DNS loop.

> May an A record “point to” a CNAME record?

No, that is not possible. An A record should point to an IPv4 address.

> May a PTR record “point to” a CNAME record?

Yes, this is allowed. Note, however, that the name server will not continue resolving the CNAME record, as the PTR record always only returns its value.

> May an NS record “point to” a CNAME record?

No, current BIND implementations, ignore these records. BIND ignores these records to prevent spoofing.