# Bind9 Returning SERVFAIL for custom Zones

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I'm trying to setup a DNS-Server for my Domains using Bind. The Server behaves correctly for noncustom Domains like `google.com` or `github.com`, but for my domains it always returns "SERVFAIL". I've already checked the zone file using `named-checkzone` which returns "OK".

My Zone config (defined in `named.conf.local`):

```
zone "michlfranken" {
  type master;
  file "/var/cache/bind/db.isiko404.dev";
};
```

My Options File:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        forwarders {
                80.241.218.68;
                46.182.19.48;
        };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation yes;

        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        listen-on { any; };
};
```

Comment: `SERVFAIL` should appear in your logfiles, did you look at them. Also it is not a good idea to have both recursive and authoritative service on the same server. And are you sure about `zone "michlfranken"`? This is not a FQDN inside the IANA root.

Comment: Yeah, clarification about the zone name would be nice. named.conf may also help and named logs would also be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RHS (right-hand-side) of NS record CANNOT be a CNAME, it must be canonical name, defined as either or both A and AAA records. This is described here: [In DNS can an IN NS point to a CNAME?](https://serverfault.com/questions/222641/in-dns-can-an-in-ns-point-to-a-cname)

This is your NS record:

```
vesemir:~> dig @81.169.234.207 isiko404.dev ns +short
h2869709.stratoserver.net.
dns.isiko404.dev.
```

This is your dns.isiko404.dev record:

```
vesemir:~> dig @81.169.234.207 dns.isiko404.dev +norecurse +noall +answer
dns.isiko404.dev.       21600   IN      CNAME   s1.isiko404.dev.
s1.isiko404.dev.        21600   IN      A       81.169.234.207
```

Now, the name in `zone` clause should be your zone name and I guess it is "isiko404.dev", not "michlfranken".

I must say I am puzzled why I can query your server and don't see the error.

Comment: The zone is not defined as `isiko404.dev` in the configuration snippet given...

Comment: "The RHS (right-hand-side) of NS record CANNOT be a CNAME, it must be canonical name, defined as either or both A and AAA records." This is true but in practice not a fatal error in `named-checkzone` AFAIK and not something that would triggerr a `SERVFAIL`.

Comment: Just noticed mismatch in zone name. Let's wait for indication if I guessed right...

Comment: It seems to have been the mismatch in the zone name, I gues copy and past has it's down sides :D I'll look into that CNAME

About you being able to query my Server, I'm switching from CoreDNS to Bind and just had CoreDNS running while Bind was down